odoo 17 view_id or model
I'll put you in context.
I tell you what I need to do. I have some data saved from the database that is saved in the street field and I added a new module that adds new organized fields, so since there is already information in the street field I need to validate if the street field does not have has information, make the address_type, address_number field mandatory, otherwise let it register, that should work for both creating and editing, I already have the contacts part but it is making it difficult for me with the users.
I need to validate fields in model=res.partner contact form. It turns out that this form is shared in different parts of Odoo such as: purchases, sales, users configurations.
So when I create or modify contacts in the contacts view, the validations that I declare to the code work well.
but when I want to create a record from user configurations, the validations that I declare for contacts also work and they block the user records.
I found a way to capture the modal from python code like this:
context = dict(self.env.context)
model = context.get('active_model', '')

This statement helps me capture the model that is declared in the Odoo models but it only captures the one from: "res.config.settings" The other models arrive empty because they do not have that field declared. There is a form that comes from the user configuration that does not share this model and since it is a user, the fields of the contact form are validated.
Below I share all my python code. I thank you very much for the help, it is very valuable:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError, UserError
import re

# my_contact_extension/models/res_partner.py

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    # Campos obligatorios
    vat = fields.Char(string="NIT", required=True)
    vat_vd = fields.Char(string='Dígito verificador', size=1, help='VD')
    ciiu = fields.Many2many('ciiu', string='Clasificador CIIU')
    zip_id = fields.Many2one('res.city.zip', string='Código postal')
    mobile = fields.Char(string='Móvil', required=True)
    email = fields.Char(string='Correo electrónico', required=True)
    property_account_position_id = fields.Many2one('account.fiscal.position', string='Posición Fiscal', required=True)
    birthday_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de Cumpleaños")
    
    # campos de direccion de la dian
    address_type = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='street_dian.nomenclature_dian')
    address_number = fields.Char()
    address_numer2 = fields.Char()
    address_numer3 = fields.Char()
    
    
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        print(f"[INFO] Modelo de create modulo contacts_fields_required")
        
        context = dict(self.env.context)
        model = context.get('active_model', '')
        
        if vals["category_id"] == "":
            if model != "res.config.settings":
                # if not "message_bounce" in vals:
                # Validar que el campo street no esté vacío
                if vals.get('street')==None or vals.get('street') ==False:
                    if (vals.get('address_type')==None or vals.get('address_type')==False) and (vals.get('address_number')==None or vals.get('address_number')==False):
                        raise UserError("los campos Tipo direccion, Nombre direccion, # y complemento son obligatorios.")
                if 'vat' in vals:
                    vals['vat'] = vals['vat'].strip().lower()
                    self._check_unique_vat_res_parther(vals['vat'])
                return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
        return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
        

    def write(self, vals):
        print(f"[INFO] Modelo de write modulo contacts_fields_required")
        context = dict(self.env.context)
        model = context.get('active_model', '')
        
        # validamos el campo vat 1, normalizamos 2, sea unico
        if model != "res.config.settings":
            if len(str(self.street)) <= 3:
                if not 'address_type' in vals:
                    if len(self.parent_id) < 1:
                        raise UserError("los campos Tipo direccion, Nombre direccion, # y complemento son obligatorios.")

        # Normalizar el valor de vat antes de escribir el registro
        if 'vat' in vals:
            if vals['vat'] != bool(False):
                vals['vat'] = vals['vat'].strip().lower()
            # Validar la unicidad del VAT
        return super(ResPartner, self).write(vals)

    def _check_unique_vat_res_parther(self, vat, current_id=None):
        if vat:
            # Buscar otros registros con el mismo NIT
            duplicate = self.search([
                ('vat', '=', vat),
                ('id', '!=', current_id)
            ], limit=1)
            if duplicate:
                raise UserError("El NIT debe ser único. El registro duplicado es: %s" % duplicate.name)
    
    
    # metodos que estan funcionando correctamente
    @api.constrains('person_type', 'vat_type', 'vat')
    def _check_vat_type_validations(self):
        for record in self:
                
            if record.person_type == "1":
                if record.vat_type != "31":
                    raise UserError("Para personas Juridicas SOLO esta permitido NIT, Por favor validar el campo Tipo de documento!")
                if record.vat != False:
                    if not re.match(r'^\d{1,9}$', record.vat):
                        raise UserError("El campo NIT debe contener menos o 9 caracteres numéricos.")
                
            # Validar que vat solo contenga números
            if record.vat != False:
                if not re.match(r'^\d+$', record.vat):
                    raise UserError("El campo NIT debe contener solo caracteres numéricos.")
                if record.person_type != "1":
                    if not re.match(r'^\d{1,10}$', record.vat):
                        raise UserError("El campo NIT debe contener menos o 10 caracteres numéricos.")

